# MAUI Databinding with CommandParameter return null

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, maui

```xml
<Grid Grid.Row="3">
    <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding GarbageCollectionModels}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type model:GarbageCollectionModel}">
                <Grid>
                    <Button x:DataType="vm:ConfiguratorViewModel"
                                Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:ConfiguratorViewModel}}, Path=DeleteInstanceCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</Grid>
```

```cs
[RelayCommand]
private async void DeleteInstance(GarbageCollectionModel garbageCollection)
{
    SendTestText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(garbageCollection);
}
```

Null will be returned after click the button. This only happens in Release mode and not in debug in Visual Studio 2022 prew. Everything is done on the android platform.

Comment: Try DataTemplate [x:DataType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings#use-compiled-bindings-in-a-datatemplate) without the x:Type: x:DataType="model:GarbageCollectionModel".

Comment: ... and: Is CommandParameter from ConfiguratorViewModel or GarbageCollectionModel?

Comment: @Benl - `{Binding .}` in a DataTemplate refers to a bound item of the CollectionView. It will be the corresponding list element of `GarbageCollectionModels`.

Comment: Will CommandParameter be bound to `GarbageCollectionModel` (assuming it is the list element of `GarbageCollectionModels`) with "<Button x:DataType="vm:ConfiguratorViewModel" " ?

Answer (score -1):

After changed to this code and rebuild solution, binding started working.

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="model:GarbageCollectionModel">
```